# How to pass the runtime arguments in kubectl while creating/running the pods?

Tags: java, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have a Spring batch application with few jobs and it is being executed as highlighted below

```
java -jar /appl/myapp/my-bat-spr-jobs-*.jar  updtTablJob 
 
java -cp /opt/mqm/java/lib/com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar:/appl/myapp/my-bat-spr-jobs-*.jar com.demo.jobs.mappingApp  jsonToQueue
```

I have defined my docker file like mentioned below

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
ENV my-bat-spr-jobs.jar
WORKDIR /root/apps
COPY . /appl/myapp
ENTRYPOINT ["java "]
```

I want to deploy/run this dockerized application on Azure Kubernetes.

I have defined my POD.YAML as mentioned below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
 name: my_app
 labels:
  app: my_app
spec:
 containers:
  - name: my_app
    image: docker:5000/path_to_my_custom_image
```

How do I deploy the POD with the required cmd args - like "-jar /appl/myapp/my-bat-spr-jobs-*.jar  updtTablJob" or "-cp /opt/mqm/java/lib/com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar:/appl/myapp/my-bat-spr-jobs-*.jar com.demo.jobs.mappingApp  jsonToQueue"?

should I just run the image without defining the POD definition? something like below?

```
kubectl run -ti --rm test --image=path_to_my_custom_image --namespace default -- sh -c "-jar /appl/myapp/my-bat-spr-jobs-*.jar  updtTablJob"

kubectl run -ti --rm test --image=path_to_my_custom_image --namespace default -- sh -c "-cp /opt/mqm/java/lib/com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar:/appl/myapp/my-bat-spr-jobs-*.jar com.demo.jobs.mappingApp  jsonToQueue"
```

My intention is to spin up the container, execute the job based on the runtime arg & destroy the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in the running parameters through the command parameter or the args parameter (even env)

As follows:

**deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: "test"
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: "test"
          image: "test:v1.0"
          {{- if .Values.command }}
          command:
            {{ toYaml .Values.command | nindent 12 }}
          {{- end }}
          {{- if .Values.args }}
          args:
            {{ toYaml .Values.args | nindent 12 }}
          {{- end }}
          {{- if .Values.env }}
          env:
            {{ toYaml .Values.env | nindent 12 }}
          {{- end }}
```

1. if use command

**values.yaml**

```
command:
  - java
  - -jar
  - /appl/myapp/my-bat-spr-jobs-*.jar
  - updtTablJob
```

2. if use args

**values.yaml**

```
args:
  - -cp
  - /opt/mqm/java/lib/com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar:/appl/myapp/my-bat-spr-jobs-*.jar com.demo.jobs.mappingApp
  - jsonToQueue
```

3. if use env

**values.yaml**

```
args:
  - $env0
  - $env1
  - $env2

env:
  - name: "env0"
    value: "-cp"
  - name: "env1"
    value: "/opt/mqm/java/lib/com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar:/appl/myapp/my-bat-spr-jobs-*.jar com.demo.jobs.mappingApp"
  - name: "env2"
    value: "jsonToQueue "
```

Comment: Thank you, I understood that we could pass the requried commandline args using command/args/env however I have multiple jobs with different values and I should be able to specify the job to be executed while deploying/running the containers. If I have it in HELM, I may need an individual values.yaml  per job, correct?

Comment: There is no need to write multiple values.yaml files, just define all the variables in one file, and you can distinguish them by different keys. It is enough to refer to different variables on different jobs in job.yaml. If your multiple jobs are created through a loop, then you only need to use the if keyword to determine whether you need to add parameters