# AKS autoscale with runtime params

Tags: azure, azure-aks

I have an exe application that runs as a service... this exe listens to a queue and it process the data inside it...

Am trying to deploy this exe into AKS with autosale on... but the problem is that we use this exe to monitor multiple queues that is added by the user at run time from a web api..

So when the user wants to monitor queue x... the api call the exe file and pass x as a startup parameter and the exe will automatically knows the name of the queue that he is supposed to listening to.

The plan that every instance of this exe will run on a separate pod.

**My questions are**:

How can the we start a pod and pass a parameter to it at run time?

And what will happen when this pod scales up will it maintain these parameters for the new pods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the parameter to during run time of pod through the command parameter or the args parameter or env.

Run a particular image on the cluster.

**Create and run a particular image, possibly replicated. Creates a deployment or job to manage the created container(s).**

```
kubectl run NAME --image=image [--env="key=value"] [--port=port] [--replicas=replicas] [--dry-run=bool] [--overrides=inline-json] [--command] -- [COMMAND] [args...]
```

You can take reference of this [***Document***](https://jamesdefabia.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_run/) for more information and examples.

***Also would suggest you to go though this [***SO thread***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68890016/how-to-pass-the-runtime-arguments-in-kubectl-while-creating-running-the-pods) here they have disscused also same requirement.It would give you great explantion as well.***

> And what will happen when this pod scales up will it maintain these
> parameters for the new pods?

Yes this will be the same for scaled pods, as scaled pods are replica's of created pods.